# How to get the max value of $1 / \sec x$ using a graph?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I understand that the max value of $1 / \sec x = 1$ mathematically.

[image: Sec x graph]

However graphically, I don't understand it. To get the max value of 1 / sec x, sec x has to be the minimum value which is undefined on the graph. So can someone explain how to solve this graphically?

Comment: $\sec x$ has to assume its minimum positive value. All the values below $-1$ are 'flipped' to be greater than $1/-1=-1$ *yet still below zero*, so only the positive ones count

Comment: @FShrike Why are they 'flipped'?

Comment: because $x\mapsto1/x$ is a decreasing function

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph of the function $f(x) = 1/x$, which maps large positive values to tiny positive values (and vice versa), but maps large *negative* values to tiny *negative* values (and vice versa) as well. Note further that $f(1)=1$ and $f(-1)=-1$.

From that graph you now can graphically deduce $g(x) = (f\circ\sec )(x) = 1/\sec(x)$: Obviously you would have $g(\pi\cdot 2k)=+1$, $g(\pi/2\cdot(2k+1))=0$, $g(\pi\cdot(2k+1))=-1$, each for any integer $k$. Moreover you get that $y=g(x)$ would oscilate endlessly between $+1$ and $-1$.

(In fact, since $\sec(x):=1/\cos(x)$ you would get $g(x) = 1/\sec(x)=\cos(x)$.)

However already the first graphical consideration shows that $y=g(x)$ surely has not only a well-defined maximum ($y=+1$), but also a well-defined minimum ($y=-1$).

--- rk